# SEDE cannot handle very basic query to show all comments with scores greater than zero

Tags: support, data-explorer

I run the following query on SEDE.

```
SELECT postID [Post Link], Score, Text
FROM 
    Comments
WHERE Score > 0
ORDER BY Score Desc
```

This is a very simple and basic query to find the highly voted comments.

IT gives the following error.

Line 1: The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and **only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions**. Please simplify the query. If you believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer Support Services for more information.

But this is not an extremely complex queriy or query that reference a very large number of tables or partitions.

Comment: *"But this is not [a] ... query that reference a very large number of tables or partitions."* It's not? Seems like there would be an awful lot of comments stored in the database on Stack Overflow, wouldn't you think?

Comment: Using `[Post Link]` is actually considered complex because it requires an implicit call to the Posts table to generate a link for every single comment being returned. You're expecting a public service to do an insane amount of data processing without any limit...

Comment: @animuson Posts table? I have used only Comments table?

Comment: @animuson And when I add  LIMIT 10 it returns Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.

Comment: Why would you expect t-SQL to not "show" an "incorrect syntax" error for [incorrect syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10440057/11407695)? What SEDE operates on is not a MySQL database

Comment: If you want to "limit" the amount of rows you need to use `TOP` or `OFFSET...FETCH` @PresidentofFoolishPeople (obviously with an `ORDER BY`).

Comment: Not sure what is happening here, but you've deleted and undeleted this question 25 or more times. That's just annoying; there's never any reason for that.

Comment: Related: [Out-of-resources when trying to run a popular DataExplorer query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284040/out-of-resources-when-trying-to-run-a-popular-dataexplorer-query) (found by @rene)

Answer (score 2):

In my answer on [Out-of-resources when trying to run a popular DataExplorer query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284040/out-of-resources-when-trying-to-run-a-popular-dataexplorer-query) I explain why you get that error despite SEDE / SQL Server giving the impression you run a simple query.

Applying what I explain in my answer on MSE to your specific case with the goal to not have SQL Server bark [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1485228/sede-cannot-handle-very-basic-query-to-show-all-comments-with-scores-greater-than) will achieve that:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(
           'site://q/'
         , Posts.Id
         , '|'
         , CASE WHEN Posts.PostTypeId = 1 THEN 'Q' ELSE 'A' END
         , ' - '
         , Questions.Title) [Link]
     , Comments.Score
     , Comments.Text
FROM 
    Comments
INNER JOIN
    Posts ON Posts.Id = Comments.PostId
INNER JOIN 
    Posts Questions ON Questions.Id = COALESCE(Posts.ParentId, Posts.Id)
WHERE Comments.Score > 0
ORDER BY Comments.Score Desc
```

This one barely completes under 120 seconds so if Stack Overflow takes on more posts and comments in the next 6 to 8 weeks it might timeout in the future.

In general you're better off if you first limit your resultset drastically (say less than 1,000 rows) and then have a projection that uses one of the magic columns.

We do have an [excellent tutorial for the Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the unforgettable  [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).